# Powerline font shapes slanted only in prompt

Tags: bash, fonts, prompt

I've got a fresh install of Ubuntu Budgie on a VMWare guest.  I use Tilix for my terminal.

I installed the powerline fonts on my system to have access to the various shapes it provides.

Regardless of the font I use in my terminal (currently FiraCode Regular).  For some reason, the symbol I'm using appears slanted (italicized?) in my prompt-- see image.

[image]

In the actual file, there's a commented example that is NOT slanted (in vim):

[image]

What's going on here?  How can I fix the issue?